# How to push new row which is blank

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

The user has the ability to add a row of fields if he would like to request multiple dates. However I am having an issue: when the row is added it is pre-filled with the values from the initial row. Additionally, any changes made are applied to all the fields so in the end all the fields have the same values. How can I fix this?

Here is my controller file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

let date = new Date();



interface Supervisor {
  name: string;
  code: string;
}
interface LeaveCode {
  name: string;
  code: string;
}




@Component({
  selector: 'app-fill-request',
  templateUrl: './fill-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fill-request.component.css']
})

export class FillRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('testForm') public test1234Form: NgForm;



  ngOnInit() {

    let today = new Date();
    let month = today.getMonth();
    let year = today.getFullYear();
    let nextMonth = (month === 11) ? 0 : month + 4;
    this.minDate = new Date(Date.now() - 12096e5);
    this.maxDate = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1));
    this.maxDate.setMonth(nextMonth);
  }

  // dates: SelectItem[];

  supervisor2: Supervisor[];
  selectedSupervisor2: Supervisor;

  leaveCodes2: LeaveCode[];
  selectedLeaveCode2: LeaveCode;

  // clicks: number = 0;
  dates = [1] //Initiazling date array

  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;
  fromDate: Date;
  toDate: Date;
  fromDateMin: Date;
  toDateMin: Date;
  fromDateMax: Date;
  toDateMax: Date;
  fromTime: Date;
  toTime: Date;


  // Method to add dates on button click for up to 4 dates
  onAddClicked() {
    if (this.dates.length < 8)
      this.dates.push(1);
  }
  //Method to remove dates on button click. Will always have one date field displayed
  onRemoveClicked() {
    if (this.dates.length > 1) this.dates.pop();
  }

  submit(): void {

    this.router.navigate(["submitted"]);


  }





  // Array of Supervisors
  constructor(private router: Router, ) {

    this.supervisor2 = [
      { name: 'Joe Rogan', code: 'JR' },
      { name: 'Alex Jones', code: 'AJ' },
      { name: 'Sam Smith', code: 'SS' },
    ];
    //Array of Leave Codes
    this.leaveCodes2 = [
      { name: 'Personal Leave', code: 'PL' },
      { name: 'Sick Leave', code: 'SL' },
      { name: 'Vacation Leave', code: 'VL' },
    ];

  }


}
```

Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
  <div class="Dates" *ngFor="let dateline of dates">

                <div class="ui-g form-group">
                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-1" id="test">
                        <button pButton type="button" id="deleteButton" icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger" (click)="onRemoveClicked()"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2" id="test">
                        <!-- Leave code field -->
                        <p-dropdown [options]="leaveCodes2" [(ngModel)]="selectedleaveCodes2" name="selectedleaveCodes2" placeholder="Leave Code*" optionLabel="name" required></p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2" id="test">
                        <!-- Start date & time fields -->
                        <p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="fromDate" name="fromDate" [minDate]="minDate" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="From Date*" id="setter" required>
                        </p-calendar>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2" id="test">
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fromTime" name="fromTime" placeholder="Input Time*" style="height: 2.186em" size="7" maxlength="8" pInputText required>
                        <!-- <p-inputMask mask="99:99 aa" placeholder="Select Time"></p-inputMask>  -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2" id="test">
                        <!-- End date & time fields -->
                        <p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="toDate" name="toDate" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="To Date*" id="setter" required></p-calendar>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2" id="test">
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="toTime" name="toTime" placeholder="Input Time*" style="height: 2.186em" size="7" maxlength="8" pInputText required>
                    </div>





                </div>

            </div>
            <button pButton type="button" id="addButton" icon="pi pi-plus" class="ui-button-success" (click)="onAddClicked()"></button>
            <br><br><br>


            <!-- Action buttons to add or remove dates. Submit button available -->
            <div class=modButtons>
                <div class="ui-g-12">
                    <!-- <button pButton type="button" label="Add Dates +" class="ui-button-success" (click)="onAddClicked()"></button> -->

                    <!--<button pButton type="submit" label="Submit" [disabled]="testForm.invalid" (click)="submit()" 
                      class="ui-button-success" id="righter"></button>-->

                    <button pButton type="submit"  class="ui-button-primary"  style="white-space:nowrap;margin:10px;"   label="Submit"   [disabled]="testForm.invalid||!(testForm.valid&&testForm.dirty)"  (click)="submit()"></button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding on single properties to all the elements like

```
<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="fromDate" name="fromDate" [minDate]="minDate" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="From Date*" id="setter" required>
</p-calendar>
```

Here you are binding `fromDate` and which will be the same for all elements added by the button.

I suggest you use an object array like `dates: {date:string, fromDate: string}[];` an populate your DOM.

Then in `onAddedClicked()`

```
onAddClicked() {
    if (this.dates.length < 8)
      this.dates.push({date:"", fromDate:""});
  }
```

Comment: That date array should be set in the controller file correct? And it would contain all the fields needed such as dates: {leaveCode:string, fromDate: string, fromTime: string, toDate:string, toTime:string}[];

Comment: Yes you should at it in the controller cmopnent and declare the fields that you need in it like date, fromDate toDate etc

Comment: So i have declared it in my controller. Im not sure how to instantiate it so that I have one blank field as soon as the page loads